# If an AJAX REST API succeeds or fails, how do I access the request headers within the success or error callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, api

For example, I have:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
    data: { name: 'random name' },
    headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'XYZ' },
    success: function(successResp) {
      console.log(successResp);
    },
    error: function(errorResp){
        console.log(errorResp);
    }
});
```

How can I access 'x-my-custom-header' from the request header within success or error callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't explicitly include a `context` property in the `$.ajax()` settings, then in your "success" etc. handlers `this` will refer to the settings object itself. Thus, `this.headers` will give you the additional header properties.

[More information at MDN.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Store your header in a variable.

```
let customHeader = { 'x-my-custom-header': 'XYZ' };
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
data: { name: 'random name' },
headers: customHeader,
success: function(successResp) {
  console.log(customHeader);
},
error: function(errorResp){
    console.log(customHeader);
}});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, as `request` object is accessible if requesting from success callback as third parameter:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url:'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
data: { name: 'random name' },
headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'XYZ' },
success: function(data, textStatus, request){
    alert(request.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
},
error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(request.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
}
```

});

And for more details, please visit : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The OP is asking about **request** headers.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for request headers.